# jquery if statement to hide elements

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to figure out how to simply **hide the "prev" button when I'm on the first div and hide the "next" button when I'm on the last div**.

Hoping there's a pro out there who'd like to help a newb. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      div { width:40px; height:40px; margin:10px; float:left; border:2px blue solid; padding:2px; }
      span { font-size:14px; }
      p { clear:left; margin:10px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="start"></div>
  <div></div>
  <p><button id="prev">Prev</button></p>
  <p><button id="next">Next</button></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $curr = $("#start");
        $curr.css("background", "#f99");
        $("#prev").click(function () {
            $curr = $curr.prev();
            $("div").css("background", "");
            $curr.css("background", "#f99");
        });
        var $curr = $("#start");
        $curr.css("background", "#f99");
        $("#next").click(function () {
            $curr = $curr.next();
            $("div").css("background", "");
            $curr.css("background", "#f99");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Presumably you're paging through the `div` elements, that are siblings to `#start"`?

Comment: Did you take a look at my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $curr = $("#start");
$curr.css("background", "#f99");
$("#prev").click(function () {
    $("#next").show();
    $curr = $curr.prev('div');
    $("div").css("background", "");
    $curr.css("background", "#f99");
    if (!$curr.prev('div').length) $(this).hide();
 });
 $("#next").click(function () {
    $("#prev").show();
    $curr = $curr.next('div');
    $("div").css("background", "");
    $curr.css("background", "#f99");
    if (!$curr.next('div').length) $(this).hide();
 });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v6Zxv/2/)

Comment: when I swap my script for this one it's definetely closer but still very buggy. The script is acting like the <p> tags are <div> tags and the next button is hidden once the <p> tag that wraps the button is active.

Comment: @ComputerGuy - updated it to filter out some elements, and should also work with more/less divs.

Comment: After touching up this code a bit the page worked as I hoped. Thanks! ...I added: $("#prev").hide(); to hide the button on load. Then changed the index in the prev button click event to "0" and the index in the next button click event to 3. Lastly I changed the "start" div to the first div and now I have exactly what I need. In hindsight I can see I didn't ask the question exactly the way I needed to and left the "start" 'id' in the wrong <div>

Comment: My comment from before was regarding the previous code you wrote. I just saw your fiddle page and the updated code no doubt works as requested! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I made a slight modification to your markup, one that reflects the conventional approach to this type of issue.

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div>F</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>W</div>
    <div class="active">L</div>
    <div>X</div>
</div>
<p><button id="prev">Prev</button></p>
<p><button id="next">Next</button></p>​
```

Note the container `.boxes` around all of our `div` elements. Additionally, note that we are no longer using an `id`, but rather a class (`.active`) that will track our current location.

```
// When the #prev or #next buttons within a p are clicked
$("p").on("click", "#prev, #next", function(e){
    // Find reference to current active element, and remove class
    var active = $(".active").removeClass("active");
    // If we have an active element
    active.length
        // Determine direction of action 
        ? $(this).prop("id") === "prev"
              // If the #prev button was clicked, move back a sibling
              ? active.prev().addClass("active")
              // If the #next button was clicked, move forward a sibling
              : active.next().addClass("active")
        // No active element? Set the first child as active
        : $(".boxes :first-child").addClass("active");  
    // Show or hide #prev and #next based on active element location
    $("#prev").toggle( !$(".active").is(":first-child") );
    $("#next").toggle( !$(".active").is(":last-child") );
// Trigger this on load to setup active element if not already present
}).find("#prev").trigger("click");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txpj2/2/

Comment: While mine works as the OP asked for it to, yours is the most elegant!

Comment: I tried swapping out my script with this one and nothing took place at all. However I went through the fiddle page and yeah this works great!

Comment: @ComputerGuy Look at the markup changes that I made. Note that I'm using a class to track the active element, rather than an id. And I also placed all of the divs within a container.

Answer (score 1):

To hide an element with jQuery use to following syntax:

```
$("#prev").hide();
```

This will hide the **Prev** button.

Comment: Yes that will hide the prev button. But my question is conditional. I only want the button to be hidden if I'm on the *first div.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding an ID to the very first div and to the very last div just in case your index numbers changes because you have added or removed divs

see change

```
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="start"></div>
  <div id="last"></div>
```

Here's the whole thing working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      div { width:40px; height:40px; margin:10px; float:left; border:2px blue solid; padding:2px; }
      span { font-size:14px; }
      p { clear:left; margin:10px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="start"></div>
  <div id="last"></div>
  <p><button id="prev">Prev</button></p>
  <p><button id="next">Next</button></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $curr = $("#start");
        $curr.css("background", "#f99");
        $("#prev").click(function () {
                $("#next").show();
                $curr = $curr.prev();
                $("div").css("background", "");
                $curr.css("background", "#f99");
            if ($curr.attr("id")) == "first") {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        $("#next").click(function () {
            $("#prev").show();
            $curr = $curr.next();
            $("div").css("background", "");
            $curr.css("background", "#f99");
            if ($curr.attr("id") == "last") {
                $(this).hide();
            }

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

See the jsfiddle and code below with the correct answer, the other answers aren't as complete.  This version will ensure no matter how many divs are within the container, the prev / next buttons will be hidden properly.

```
var updateButtons = function() {
    var $curr = $(".current");

    if ($curr.prev().length > 0)
        $("#prev").show();
    else
        $("#prev").hide();

    if ($curr.next().length > 0)
        $("#next").show();
    else
        $("#next").hide();
};

var $curr = $("#start");
$curr.css("background", "#f99");
$("#prev").click(function () {
    $curr.removeClass("current");
    $curr = $curr.prev();
    $("div").css("background", "");
    $curr.css("background", "#f99");
    $curr.addClass("current");
    updateButtons();
});
var $curr = $("#start");
$curr.css("background", "#f99");
$("#next").click(function () {
    $curr.removeClass("current");
    $curr = $curr.next();
    $("div").css("background", "");
    $curr.css("background", "#f99");
    $curr.addClass("current");
    updateButtons();
});

updateButtons();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rFs7Q/1/

Comment: when I swap my script to this one and load the page *both buttons are hidden on page load.

Comment: You need to put the current class on your #start div.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ukacuq/7/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
var curr = 3;  // SET DESIRED START N (Remember: zero based)
var divN = $('div').length;

function doit(){
  $('div').eq(curr % divN).css("background", "#f99").siblings('div').css("background", "#fff");
}doit();

$("#prev, #next").click(function (e) {
 var set = this.id === 'prev' ? curr-- : curr++ ;
  doit();
});
```